# Reset zoom doesn't adhere to axis extremes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to get the "Rest Zoom" button not to go all the way back 
and show the entire graph, but to adhere to the axis's extremes. 
Example http://jsfiddle.net/rDts7/ 
So when you zoom further in here, the "Reset Zoom" 
button would only go back to the extremes, is that possible?

Comment: alternatively a way to dynamically set min or max in yAxis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could push the Reset Zoom completely off the chart using:

```
resetZoomButton: {position: {x: 1000, y: 1000}}
```

Then use a combination of the getExtremes and/or setExtremes methods to produce your desired result.  You can find the definition for the two methods here: [Axis Object Methods](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#axis-object)

Comment: I ended up rebuilding the Chart each time I give it different parameters, that did the trick, and made more sense because the data was different.